# How to make custom environment works like production environment in expressJs?

Tags: node.js, express, configuration-files

I am new to `nodeJs+ExpressJs app` setup. I would like to run `app.js` in a custom environment.

For an example:
     `NODE_ENV=production node app.js` will run the app in `production` mode and the view templates will be `cached`. But there is an option, that we can run the `app.js` in any custom mode like `NODE_ENV=custom_environment node app.js`. If it is the case, how to catch the view templates ? or will it catch for all the environment mode ? In-terms of `development` mode, I don't think view templates are cached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose which settings are used for which environment using `app.configure`:

```
app.configure('custom_environment', function() {
  app.enable('view cache'); // enable view cache for this environment
  // perhaps load middleware specific for your custom environment:
  app.use(...);
});
```